# Icons to indicate Usage and Dosage

Tags: icons

Looking for suggestions for an icon on our website to indicate correct dosage and usage of medication.

Comment: Are you looking for one icon or two?

Comment: You are in Israel so I can't speak to your country's regulations, but in the US, the FDA has very specific requirements for communicating dosages and usages that one must follow first and foremost.

Comment: @DA01 I'm the one in Israel, not the OP (afaik) :)

Answer (score 3):

What about an [Erlenmeyer flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlenmeyer_flask)?

Comment: I have never used that to take any medication. It reminds me more of chemical stuff than of medication.

Comment: @BartGijssens As a gamer, it reminds me of consumables that would heal or empower me.

Comment: @MicronXD good point. But it's not really the case if the flask is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could just have a count of [pills](http://thenounproject.com/noun/pill/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the pharmaceutical industry has standard pictograms for such things. You can download some of those pictograms here:

http://www.usp.org/audiences/consumers/pictograms/form.html

You may also want to take a look at this example:

[image]

Found here: http://www.123rf.com/photo_8954864_pharmaceutical-dosage-icons.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a general icon to communicate the concept of dosage (i.e. "Dosage Info Here") information, or specific iconography to communicate dosage instructions (i.e. "Take 2 pills every 4 hours")?

I've worked on a very extensive medication dosing icon project. I did about 300 icons as broad exploration and then several of those were tested with consumers over a period of several months and many rounds of iteration.

If you are looking for a general icon, you can't go wrong with something like pills falling into a hand, or a bottle with some pills next to it.

For more specific iconographic instruction, the key takeaway is to be as literal as possible. If the instruction is to take 2 pills, the icon must incorporate 2 pills. You cannot use a clock as an abstract representation of time — if the hands on the clock read 3:45, someone will believe they are being instructed to take pills at 3:45. What works best is more illustrative instruction. If I am being told to take 1 pill every 12 hours, I should see a single pill maybe falling into a hand with text underneath that says "every 12 hrs".

Having worked in this space, I can tell you I really wanted iconography to work, but there were few cases where the icons helped compliance without creating more problems. The key to better compliance with medical information is going to depend more on typographic hierarchy and clear organization and language.

Answer (score 0):

The noun project has a bunch of good icons for health & wellness at http://thenounproject.com/category/healthcare-wellness/

Answer (score 0):

A spoon?

Medication spoons seem to come in standard sizes.

Comment: Most medication is taken without the use of a spoon.

Answer (score 0):

try icon finder, it may help http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=medical

Comment: you can choose the size of the icons you need as well